# SQL Stored Procedure to handle several null parameters?

Tags: sql, parameters

On SQL Server I am trying to be able to select * records from a table with four parameters, in some cases the incoming parameter will be a certain string value 'Select', in that case I would like to select * from the specified field.

Does anyone know of a good way to handle this?

```
(
 @mParameter varchar(50) = Null,
 @tParameter varchar(50) = Null,
 @gParameter int = Null,
 @nParameter varchar(255) = Null
)

as



Select
  *

From
  TableA

Where

If @mParameter = 'Select' then
  M = @mParameter


If @tParameter = 'Select' then
AND
  T = @tParameter

If @gParameter = 'Select'then
AND
  G = @gParameter

If @nParameter = 'Select' then
AND
  N = @nParameter
```

Comment: This is confusing. Are you saying "if mParameter isn't null, then it has the value to match"? Or do you really mean "if mParameter = 'select'"? Because then what are you matching on??

Comment: @gParameter is NEVER going to be 'Select' since you made it an int.

Comment: In .NET I send a null parameter if a value from a dropdown list is 'Select', If the SP recieves a null param then I would like to not include that parameter in teh query

Comment: You'd be halfway to a solution if you replace the text 'Select' in your code with NULL, since, as you say, the SP is receiving NULL, not 'Select'

Comment: Right but if the first parameter is null i don't want to include it in teh query, and I can't start the where clause with the next parametr which would contain an AND right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2**

Try this:

```
Select *
From TableA
Where
M = isnull(@mParameter, M)
and T = isnull(@tParameter, T)
and G = isnull(@gParameter, G)
and N = isnull(@nParameter, N)
```

Comment: In .NET I send a null parameter if a value from a dropdown list is 'Select', If the SP recieves a null param then I would like to not include that parameter in teh query

Comment: @John No that doesn't make sense! haha I updated the update with the older version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Denis, This is returning results.

Comment: @John: if this answer is the one you want, "accept" it (click the check mark under the number of votes)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (@mParameter = 'M' OR @mParameter IS NULL)
AND (@tParameter = 'T' OR @tParameter IS NULL)
AND (@gParameter = 123 OR @gParameter IS NULL)
AND (@nParameter = 'N' OR @nParameter IS NULL)
```